# PHP Warning: file_get_contents(http://some ip/test): failed to open stream: Connection refused yet i have enabled fopen an url include

Tags: php, apache

I'm using `file_get_contents($url, false, $context);` in my script and i get an error, connection refused. 
On the server with `some ip` I've enabled `allow_url_include` and `allow_url_fopen`, and restarted apache severally. 
in phpinfo(), it shows my changes have taken effect, my script still shows 'connection refused'
What is wrong??? Can someone help? 
This is not a duplicate please.
`$m_request["uniq"] = '123';$m_request["id"] = 'enter';$secret_key = 'xx25';$encoded = json_encode($m_request);//json encode request;$msg = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $encoded, $secret_key, true));$options = array('http' => array('header'  => "app_signature: $msg\r\n",'method'  => POST',                 content' => $encoded),);`

Comment: It could well be that the remote site is testing for a browser signature in the request, and refusing the connection if it doesn't find one

Comment: should be in the `$context` variable. or how do i false it?

Comment: works on other ips though

Comment: get back please,. am stuck while others are down-voting my  question

Comment: What are the values of $url and $context?

Comment: $url is the ip am connecting to. say 192.168.1.**  `$context = array(
    'http' => array(
     'header'  => "app_signature: $encodeddata\r\n",
     'method'  => 'POST',
     'content' => $jsonencodeddata
    ),
   );`

Comment: just edited to give more info

Comment: try to add `ignore_errors` (= true) to the http context

Comment: it has not changed. @Deadooshka is there a curl alternative to exactly that?

Comment: can't see using of `stream_context_create()` in your code. `$context` must be the `resource` of this function .

Comment: it's there. only that I've not included it in my question

Comment: check the connection itself `$fp = fsockopen('IP/host', 80, $errno, $errstr, 5); echo $errstr; fclose($fp);`. error text should be more detailed.

Comment: let  me check it, I'll get back later. I really hope it works